# naming for a german README.md on github

Tags: github, localization

Is there a standard naming convention If I want to add a german README.md file in a github project?

I could name it

```
README_de.md
```

or create a subfolder

```
/german/README.md
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often to be find in German projects: LIESMICH which is the exact translation from README. If you can use in github... why not ?

Comment: OK, thanks, now I called it `LIESMICH.md` at https://github.com/rubo77/ffmap-backend/blob/master/LIESMICH.md